# Is there a possibility that the timer trigger will be executed with a lot of delay?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

First of all, the development environment is asp.net core 2.0 (azure functions preview).
A timer trigger was triggered after a significantly later time than the defined time. (About 3 hours and 20 minutes)
It is not a time zone problem.

Under normal circumstances, how much delays should be considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timers in Azure Functions are accurate. If they fail to run or run with significant delay then it indicates there is some other underlying issue, either an application problem or a functions bug (v2 still has many bugs). Assuming you already have app insights enabled, look at the exceptions table for evidence of something going wrong before the timer stopped running.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to be a good starting point.